# Can a Telegram bot get updates about web logins?

Tags: telegram-bot

Telegram has [web login widget](https://core.telegram.org/widgets/login) allowing webpages to log users in and get their Telegram IDs. Can I have a bot that will receive an update on every web login?

I can see `connected_website` mentioned in https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message

does it mean users can only send messages explicitly to the bot?

Comment: Do you have any progress in this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that this update event sending probably **only for the first login**. So if one account never login via your bot before, telegram send udpate event with non null `connected_website` field.